# rails 3.2.9 bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am doing simple hello world project with rails but it seems it it throwing bundler error to me. I want to see how to remove the bundler errors that comes after i type

```
   rails new helloproject
```

the errors in the console are:

```
 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:271:in `<class:Path>':   uninitialized constant Bundler::GemInstaller (NameError)
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:270:in `<module:Source>'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:10:in `<module:Bundler>'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:21:in `initialize'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `new'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `evaluate'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in `block in <main>'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in `<main>'
   There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I wonder how can i get past this error and bundle the application properly?

I do manage to run the server and run the hello world app but every new project seems to throw this bundler error.

I have checked similar questions but this one seems to be unique type of the error.

How to get rid of these bundler install errors?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps,

```
gem install bundler
and after adding:

gem 'bundler'
```

in line 2 in `config/boot.rb` (just after require `'rubygems'`)

let me know if not solved.

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I also had trouble finding the boot.rb in config folder because there were multiple boot.rb files.